# Create a "for" loop for columns and rows in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have this dataframe:

```
a <- c(2,5,90,77,56,65,85,75,12,24,52,32)
b <- c(45,78,98,55,63,12,23,38,75,68,99,73)
c <- c(77,85,3,22,4,69,86,39,78,36,96,11)
d <- c(52,68,4,25,79,120,97,20,7,19,37,67)
e <- c(14,73,91,87,94,38,1,685,47,102,666,74)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

I need to convert the following script in a loop, in R:
the variable "f" indicates a column of my dataframe ("df") and I need that it ranges from 1 to 5 (that is the number of columns in my dataframe df) in the loop. Also, the loop must consider three rows at a time.
In that way, in each loop, running the script I will found a "cdf_min" for each "f" considerated.

Script:

```
f <- 1
x <- (df[1:3,f])
y <- (df[1:3,-f])
dif_2 <- (x - y)^2
summ <- colSums(dif_2)
summa <- t(as.matrix(summ))
cmin <- which(summa == apply(summa,1,min))
cdf_min <- 
  if (f <= cmin){
    cmin+1
  } else{cmin}
```

I hope I was clear.
Thanks everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the `for` loop, you could iterate `f` over the `seq`uence over the columns, and also use it as indices of the results vector `cdf_min[f]`. The `which` construction can be simplified with `which.min`

```
cdf_min <- integer(ncol(df))  ## initialize results vector

for (f in seq_len(ncol(df))) {
  x <- df[1:3, f]
  y <- df[1:3, -f]
  dif_2 <- (x - y)^2
  cmin <- which.min(colSums(dif_2))
  cdf_min[f] <- 
    if (f <= cmin) {
      cmin + 1
    } else { 
      cmin
    }
}

cdf_min
# [1] 5 5 4 3 2
```

### Edit

To also loop over subsequent row indices of length 3 from 2 to 12 - 2, which we may create a matrix `R` using `mapply`, containing the sequences in the columns.

Then we initialize a results matrix `cdf_mat` with number of rows corresponding to number of columns of `R`, and same number of columns as `df`.

Now we create an outer `for` loop, that iterates over the columns of `R`, similar to the inner loop and subsets the data frame on rows according to the sequences in the columns of `R`.

```
R <- mapply(`+`, list(2:4), 0:8) 
cdf_mat <- matrix(NA, ncol(R), ncol(df))  ## initialize results matrix

for (r in seq_len(ncol(R))) {
  for (f in seq_len(ncol(df))) {
    x <- df[R[, r], f]
    y <- df[R[, r], -f]
    dif_2 <- (x - y)^2
    cmin <- which.min(colSums(dif_2))
    cdf_mat[r, f] <- 
      if (f <= cmin) {
        cmin + 1
      } else { 
        cmin
      }
  }
}

cdf_mat
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    5    5    4    3    2
# [2,]    2    1    4    3    1
# [3,]    5    5    1    1    1
# [4,]    3    5    1    1    2
# [5,]    3    3    1    3    1
# [6,]    4    3    2    1    1
# [7,]    4    3    2    1    1
# [8,]    4    3    2    1    2
# [9,]    4    3    1    1    2
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(2, 5, 90, 77, 56, 65, 85, 75, 12, 24, 52, 
32), b = c(45, 78, 98, 55, 63, 12, 23, 38, 75, 68, 99, 73), c = c(77, 
85, 3, 22, 4, 69, 86, 39, 78, 36, 96, 11), d = c(52, 68, 4, 25, 
79, 120, 97, 20, 7, 19, 37, 67), e = c(14, 73, 91, 87, 94, 38, 
1, 685, 47, 102, 666, 74)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If I want to create a loop in the loop, for example, which subsequently considers rows 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, ..., 10:12, what should I do?

Comment: You are welcome @RobSe, please see edit.

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf, this was really helpful!! From this point, is it possible to derive a matrix in which for each "r" corresponds the result contained in "dif_2" relative to the corresponding "f" column displayed in "cdf_mat"?

Comment: @ros_ber I'm not sure if I can follow you, do you mean `dif_2/df[R[, r], -f]` right after the `dif_2` line? BTW, please note slightly improved answer.